# android mmap failed: invalid argument (errno 22)

Tags: android, linux, shared-memory

I was porting/compiling [androidvncserver](http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-server/) for my android device, but when I run it (as root) I keep getting mmap errors.

The offending code looks like this:

```
/* Android does not use /dev/fb0. */
#define FB_DEVICE "/dev/graphics/fb0"

if ((fbfd = open(FB_DEVICE, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
{
    printf("cannot open fb device %s\n", FB_DEVICE);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

<SNIP>

fbmmap = mmap(NULL, pixels * bytespp, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fbfd, 0);
if (fbmmap == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("mmap failed errno = %d\n", errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I am looking for thoughts on how to debug this further.

For the record, pixels=614400 and bytespp=4. Also, /dev/graphics/fb0 is owned by root (group=graphics), and has permissions of 660.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prmatta,

Error code 22 is `EINVAL`.

From the [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) documentation that tells you...

> EINVAL We don't like start or length
>   or offset. (E.g., they are too large,
>   or not aligned on a page boundary.)

Perhaps you didn't page align your memory?

Comment: And prmatta should note that not all systems use the same page size, so the correct macro constant should be used. I believe _POSIX_PAGESIZE is what you want.