# Mapping ARM Global Timer on Linux

Tags: linux, timer, arm

I have been able to create a baremetal application using Xilinx SDK on Zynq 7000 board to access the ARM global timer. However, I am trying to use mmap to map the ARM Global Timer in Xilinx Linux and access it. I am using the following code:

```
unsigned int global_timer_addr = 0xF8F00200;  (as defined in the xparameters.h)


global_timer_ptr = mmap(NULL, page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, global_timer_addr);
```

Whenever I try to access this virtual address, I get segmentation fault.I found that my mmap is returning an errno = 22 indicating invalid parameter. I am using mmap to map axi space in the same userspace with same parameters except the address and they work.

I suspect that this region is sort of special. As on ARM [infopage](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0407f/CACCJFCJ.html), it defines this area to be private region. I do not understand what exactly this means and what is my solution to access the arm global timer.

P.S I have come to know that the new Xilinx Linux Kernels have inbuilt drivers to access this global timer. But I am unable to build the latest kernel and use it as there is no clear cut help on how to use the timer. I am pursuing both solutions as of now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android mmap failed: invalid argument (errno 22)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780524/android-mmap-failed-invalid-argument-errno-22)

Comment: And in case it isn't already obvious, it's the offset.

Comment: @Notlikethat I did't exactly understand what you meant. The offset does seem to be the problem, but what can I do to resolve it. I did verify that the pagesize is 4096 bytes which is correct as well.

Comment: You're passing 0xF8F00200 as the offset. Is 0xF8F00200 a multiple of 4096 (i.e. aligned to the page size)? Once you've mapped the page correctly, just access smaller offsets _within_ that page.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a function to get a virtual address from the kernel.
See this video and you will find the solution
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtvVfjIm9Xw&feature=youtu.be

```c
#define MAP_SIZE 4096UL
#define MAP_MASK (MAP_SIZE - 1)

void *getvaddr(int phys_addr)
{
    void *mapped_base;
    int memfd;

    void *mapped_dev_base;
    off_t dev_base = phys_addr;

    memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC); // to open this, the program needs to be run as root
    if (memfd == -1)
    {
        printf("Can't open /dev/mem.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // Map one page of memory into user space such that the device is in that page, but it may not
    // be at the start of the page

    mapped_base = mmap(0, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memfd,
                    dev_base & ~MAP_MASK);
    if (mapped_base == (void *)-1)
    {
        printf("Can't map the memory to user space.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // get the address of the device in user space which will be an offset from the base
    // that was mapped as memory is mapped at the start of the page

    mapped_dev_base = mapped_base + (dev_base & MAP_MASK);
    return mapped_dev_base;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you could consider improving your answer by: (1) properly formatting your code; (2) describe, at least in general, the content of the video (and perhaps also why it is relevant); (3) describe what why your code is solving the problem described in the question.

Comment: The url video shows the implementation of the getvaddr() function to have a regular access to the memory space handled by the kernel. I used this function to map the timer and it works fine. Hope that this will be helpful for you